# Injective Ring Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How does one exactly find an injective ring homomorphism? It means that every element in $R_1$ is sent to a unique value in $R_2$, right? If so, then how would I go about finding an injective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$? Do I just map every element in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, with the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ going to the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$? So, would it look something like:

0 --> 0, 1 --> 1, 2 --> some value in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, 3 --> some value in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "every element  is sent to a unique value" is the definition of a function. The definition of injective is "every value taken is taken only once".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injective means that no two elements are sent to the same element (saying that ``every element in $R_1$ is mapped to a unique value in $R_2$" could be interpreted as saying that each element of $R_1$ is sent to precisely one element of $R_2$, which is simply what it means to be a function). Formally, $f$ is injective if $f(r_1) = f(r_2)$ implies $r_1 = r_2$.

To have a ring homomorphism, you need the function $f$ to be compatible with addition and multiplication; i.e., that $f(r_1 + r_2) = f(r_1) + f(r_2)$ and $f(r_1 r_2) = f(r_1) f(r_2)$ for all $r_1, r_2\in R_1$. In your case, you have it easy: once you determine where $1$ is sent, you've determined everything, since every element of $\Bbb Z_4$ is a sum of $1$'s: $0 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$, $1 = 1$, $2 = 1 + 1$, $3 = 1 + 1 + 1$. However, you need to make sure you send $1$ to an element of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ such that $4 f(1) = 0$, because $4f(1) = f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) = f(1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = f(0) = 0$ (a ring homomorphism requires that $0$ must map to $0$). Often, as Rob notes, one also requires that $f(1) = 1$, meaning that the multiplicative identity is sent to the multiplicative identity, but if you require this, there can be no ring map $\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_{12}$ at all, let alone an injective one. I'll assume you're not requiring this condition.

So to summarize, now you must determine the following. Which elements of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ satisfy $4x = 0$? For which of these $x$ would $f(1) = x$ give you an injective map?

Comment: The class does require multiplicative identities; so, then it's impossible to have an injective ring homomorphism because 4$f(1)$ can never equal to 1 in Z12?

Comment: @Max if $1$ must map to $1$, and $0$ must map to $0$, then $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, and so it follows that $0 = f(0) = f(4) = f(4\cdot 1) = 4f(1) = 4$, but $0\neq 4$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$.

Comment: Ah got it, very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Just as an exercise, if we didn't need to consider multiplicative identities, then the elements of Z12 that satisfies 4x = 0 would be only 3, right (since only 4(3) = 0 mod 12). So how would f(1) = 3 be an injective map?

Comment: Not quite. $4x = 0$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$ is satisfied by $x = 0$, $x = 3$, $x = 6$, and $x = 9$. Sending $1$ to $0$ is not injective, since $0$ must also map to $0$. If $1$ maps to $3$, then $2$ maps to $6$ and $3$ maps to $9$, so this map is injective. If $1$ maps to $6$, then $2$ maps to $0$, so it is not injective. If $1$ maps to $9$, then $2$ maps to $6$, and $3$ maps to $3$, so this map is also injective.

Comment: Oh, so the injective homomorphism would be satisfied by x = 3 and 9 then. What's the "function representation" of that? Is it $3^{n}x$ mod $12$?

Comment: In general a function need not have a nice formula. It would be perfectly acceptable to say its the additive map defined by $1\mapsto \pm3$, depending on which you're talking about. In this case, you could define a formula by saying $f(n) = \pm3n\pmod{12}$, although you would have to check that this formula is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with rings with a multiplicative identity element, a homomorphism $f$ from $R_1$ to $R_2$ is required to preserve the identity element: i.e., it has to have $f(1) = 1$ (which I should perhaps write as $f(1_{R_1}) = 1_{R_2}$). If $R_1 = \Bbb{Z}_4$ (or $\Bbb{Z}_n$ for any $n$ or $\Bbb{Z}$), then this completely determines $f$, because you must have $f(-1) = -1$ and then as any element $x$  of $R_1$ can be written as $x  = e + e + \ldots + e$ where $e$ is either $1$ or $-1$, you know that $$f(x) = f(e) + f(e) + \ldots f(e) = e + e + \ldots e$$

If $R_1 = \Bbb{Z}_4$ and $R_2 = \Bbb{Z}_{12}$ then you have a problem because in $R_1$, $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 0$, but this does not hold in $R_2$. There is no ring homomorphism injective or otherwise from $R_1$ to $R_2$ in this case.

If you are working with "rng"s, i.e., rings that are not required to have a multiplicative identity, then $f(1) = 1$ is not required and you can construct a homomorphism - see Stahl's answer.